# Permitting percent sign % in URL for IIS 7 and CF10 with odd Jakarta/ISAPI error

Tags: iis, iis-7, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I seem to be having a problem with URL's which contain a percent sign. For example this URL is okay:

`http://example.com/json.cfm/json_type/answer_grid/league/268/survey_id/323/requesttimeout/50000/team_view/0/division_id/0/group/0/return_script/1`

However, this URL fails.

`http://example.com/json.cfm/json_type/answer_grid/league/268/survey_id/323/requesttimeout/50000/team_view/0/division_id/0/group/0/return_script/%`

It seems to produce a mysterious Jakarta/ISAPI error:

> The requested URL was not found on this server! If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again. Jakarta/ISAPI/isapi_redirector/1.2.32 ()

The system seems to be rejecting the percent sign.  How can I allow this to go through? The full URL I'm trying to pass is:

`http://example.com/json.cfm/json_type/answer_grid/league/268/survey_id/323/requesttimeout/50000/team_view/0/division_id/0/group/0/return_script/%2Fmanager%5Fpro%2Ecfm%2Fleague%2F268%2Faction%2Fregistration%2Fcontent%5Faction%2Fmanagesurveys%2Ftabindex%2F1`

Notice this one DOES work

`http://example.com/json.cfm?json_type=answer_grid&league=268&survey_id=323&requesttimeout=50000&team_view=0&division_id=0&group=0&return_script=%2Fmanager%5Fpro%2Ecfm%2Fleague%2F268%2Faction%2Fregistration%2Fcontent%5Faction%2Fmanagesurveys%2Ftabindex%2F1`

I use this code on CF9 to convert the URL's and it works fine:

```
<cffunction name="set_spider_friendly_urls" access="remote" returntype="string">
    <cfset cfmx7_updated_path_info = "#cgi.script_name#/cgi.path_info"> 
    <cfif findnocase("#cgi.script_name#/",cfmx7_updated_path_info) and not len(query_string)>
        <cftry>
            <CFSET str_path=replacenocase(cgi.path_info,"#cgi.script_name#/","","all")>
            <CFSET str_path=replace(str_path,"//","/ /","all")>
            <CFSET clear=structclear(url)>
            <CFSET int_len=listlen(str_path,"/")>
            <CFSET str_delim="/">
            <cfloop index="int_cur" from="1" to="#int_len#" step="2">
                <cfif int_cur eq int_len>
                    <CFSET clear=setvariable("url.#listgetat(str_path,int_cur,str_delim)#","")>
                <cfelse>
                    <CFSET tmp_var=rereplace(listgetat(str_path,int_cur+1,str_delim),"["",/\\\*&()$%^@~´?;'']","","all")>
                    <CFSET clear=setvariable("url.#listgetat(str_path,int_cur,str_delim)#",tmp_var)>
                </cfif>
            </cfloop>
            <CFSET bln_newurl=1>
            <CFSET str_currentpage=cgi.path_info>
            <cfcatch>
                <cffile action="APPEND" file="#ExpandPath( "./" )#cc_gateway_logs\hurl.log" output="#now()#,#remote_addr#,#cgi.path_info#" addnewline="Yes">
            </cfcatch>
        </cftry>
    <cfelse>
        <CFSET str_currentpage=replacelist("#cgi.script_name#?#cgi.query_string#","?,&,=","/,/,/")>
        <CFSET bln_newurl=0>
    </cfif>
    <cfreturn cfmx7_updated_path_info>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: you need to url encode it.

Comment: now that you posted the full thing (why didn't you start by that, i wonder), it appears that the difference between your urls is not the presence of a %, but rather the presence of / or &= on one or the other version

Comment: I'm just curious where this Jakarta/ISAPI error is coming from.

Comment: Are you sure that json.cfm/json_type/answer_grid/league/268 is the same url as json.cfm?json_type=answer_grid&league=268?

Comment: Yes, I am doing a rewrite on that URL, see?

Answer (score 0):

% are usually used for encoding values, meaning most servers or services will try to decode it. You therefore need to encode it first.

`%` encodes as `%25`.